# flip BMP image horizontal in c

Tags: c, image-processing

My function is getting an Image and I am trying to flip it right or left. horizonal flip. I tried to do something like but don't have idea how to move forward

The size of the image is int height and int width and the function knows the values in pixels.

Here is my code:

```
void flip_hrizntal_pixels(struct Pixel **pixels, int height, int width)
{
    //Stuck here don't know how flip those pixels 
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            //pixels[i][j].red = 
            //pixels[i][j].green = 
            //pixels[i][j].blue = 
        }
    }

}
```

here are struct data:

```
struct Pixel
{
    unsigned char red;
    unsigned char green;
    unsigned char blue;
};
struct RGB_Image
{
    long height;
    long width;
    long size;
    struct Pixel **pixels;
};
```

i am calling this function like that :

```
struct RGB_Image image;
int status = load_image(&image); 
flip_hrizntal_pixels(image.pixels, image.height, image.width);
```

Comment: Your inner loop needs to exchange the first pixel with the last pixel and stop when it has exchanged the first half of the row with the last half.  Does that help?

Comment: Hi Stark, Thank you!  , i am sorry i am a newbie in c , don't have idea how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following C code flips RGB image left/right:

```
//Flip RGB (or BGR) image Left/Right.
//P is an array of <height> pointers.
//P[0] points first pixel of first row.
//P[1] points first pixel of second row.
//P[height-1] points first pixel of last row.
static void flip_hrizntal_pixels(Pixel **P, int height, int width)
{
    //Allocate sketch buffer for storing single flipped row.
    Pixel *R = (Pixel*)malloc(width*sizeof(Pixel));

    //Stuck here don't know how flip those pixels 
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        Pixel *I0 = P[i];    //Points first pixel in source image

        //j is destination index (index of rgb triple in source image I).
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            //Iterate source row from end of row to beginning of row.
            R[j].red    = I0[width - j - 1].red;
            R[j].green  = I0[width - j - 1].green;
            R[j].blue   = I0[width - j - 1].blue;
        }

        //Copy flipped row back to image P.
        memcpy(I0, R, width*sizeof(Pixel));
    }

    free(R);
}
```

Before executing `flip_hrizntal_pixels`, you need to prepare an array of pointers.

Computing image stride in bytes:
`stride` is the number of bytes between two consecutive rows.
For BMP format, the `stride` must be a multiple of 4 (padded up, in case width is not a multiple of 4).

```
int stride = width*3;

//For supporting width that is not a multiple of 4, stride in bytes is padded up to nearest multiple of 4 bytes.
stride = (stride + 3) & (~3);  //http://mapw.elte.hu/elek/bmpinmemory.html
```

Preparing array of pointers to rows:
Assume `I` is a pointer to the input image.

```
//Prepare and array of pointers to rows:
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//P[0] -> Points beginning of first row.
//P[1] -> Points beginning of second row.
//...
//P[height-1] -> Points beginning of last row.    
//Allocate array of <height> pointers.
Pixel **P = (Pixel**)malloc(height*sizeof(Pixel*));

for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    P[i] = (Pixel*)((char*)I + stride*i); //Advance by <stride> bytes from row to row.
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Executing `flip_hrizntal_pixels`:

```
flip_hrizntal_pixels(P,
                     height, 
                     width);
```

Cleanup:

```
free(P);
```

Testing (`peppers.png` image from MATLAB):

Input image:
[image: Before Flip]

Output image:
[image: After Flip]

Comment: Does this account for the potential padding at the end of every row?

Comment: @RetiredNinja It doesn't look like it does, but to be fair, OPs struct doesn't appear to either. As Rotem notes, the pixel order is wrong, so I think this is a custom bitmap format.

Comment: @RetiredNinja thank you! good solution, but in my program, there is already a pre-declare instruction to use struct Pixel **pixels .

Comment: Thank you @Rotem , i am wondering if you can help me to similar aproch like this one : void flip_hrizntal_pixels(struct Pixel **pixels, int height, int width) in parameters where am using struct Pixel **pixels

Comment: Done!    I warned you it's going to be messy... (after preparing the array of pointers, you can execute ARD solution too).

Answer (score 2):

Imagine that your picture is arranged as rows and columns of Pixels, each Pixel having R,G & B. Each row will have 'width' number of Pixels, and there will be such 'height' number of rows.

So, to flip on the horizontal i.e. rightmost Pixel in a row goes to the left-most and vice-versa, followed by 2nd Pixel in the same row which is exchanged with 2nd last Pixel, and so on, the code would be something like this. (PS: This is just a quick code to give you an idea how to proceed. I haven't compiled/run my code)

Hope this helps

```
void flip_hrizntal_pixels(struct Pixel **pixels, int height, int width)
{
Pixel tempPixel;

for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width/2; j++)
    {
    //make a temp copy of the 'j-th' Pixel  
    tempPixel.red = pixels[i][j].red; 
    tempPixel.green = pixels[i][j].green;  
    tempPixel.blue = pixels[i][j].blue; 


    //copy the corresponding last Pixel to the j-th pixel 
    pixels[i][j].red = pixels[i][width-j].red; 
    pixels[i][j].green = pixels[i][width-j].green; 
    pixels[i][j].blue = pixels[i][width-j].blue;


    //copy the temp copy that we made earlier of j-th Pixel to the corresponding last Pixel
    pixels[i][width-j].red = tempPixel.red;
    pixels[i][width-j].green = tempPixel.green;
    pixels[i][width-j].blue = tempPixel.blue;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Best to stop at `width/2` or you will flip them all back!

Comment: Putting everything on one line makes this very unreadable. Consider breaking it up so it can be read without scrolling right.

Comment: Thank you weston and Retired Ninja for your comments!! :-)  I've updated my answer based on your comments.  Max, if this put you in the right direction, then could you please accept the answer ?

Comment: Thank you @ARD , i am going to check it , look like nice solution :)